# how to calculate determinant value for $3\times2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am learning Rank of Matrix chapter, here I am stuck on finding the submatrices for $3\times3$ matrix and also, in case if $3\times2$ matrix is generated as submatrix for $3\times3$ matrix, I wonder how to calculate the determinant value for the following matrix. Since I am new to the topic, any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow your question talking about $3\times 2$ matrices... only square matrices have determinants.  As for how to take a determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix, there are surely hundreds or thousands of tutorials easily found throughout the internet and on this site as well that should satisfy you.

Comment: I recommend PatrickJMT's videos on the subject.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21LWuY8i6Hw

Comment: The sub-matrices generated in the evaluation of determinant of a given matrix are always square. In the case of $3\times 3$ matrix, there are 3 different sub-matrices and they are all $2\times 2$ matrices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Determinant is not defined for non-square matrices. Probably, you want to check whether rows of submatrix are linear-independent. To do so there are many different approaches, for example [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).